# Your Flutter application is created using an older version of the Android embedding. It's being deprecated in favor of Android embedding v2. Follow

Tags: flutter

Recently I joined a company and took over an old project and found these errors.

here is the log when I enter **flutter run**

Launching lib\main.dart on MI 9 in debug mode...

- /D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/path_provider_windows-0.0.4+3/lib/src/path_provider_windows_real.dart:126:25:
  Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
  - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or
  defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  knownFolderID.addressOf, KF_FLAG_DEFAULT, NULL, pathPtrPtr);
  ^^^^^^^^^
- /D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:1067:7:
  Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'LOGFONT'.
  - 'LOGFONT' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or
  defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  addressOf.cast().elementAt(28).cast();
  ^^^^^^^^^
- /D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:1112:29:
  Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class
  'ENUMLOGFONTEX'.
  - 'ENUMLOGFONTEX' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or
  defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.   LOGFONT get
  elfLogFont => addressOf.cast().ref;
  ^^^^^^^^^
- /D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:1114:29:
  Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class
  'ENUMLOGFONTEX'.
  - 'ENUMLOGFONTEX' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or
  defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.   String get
  elfFullName => addressOf
  ^^^^^^^^^
- /D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:1120:26:
  Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class
  'ENUMLOGFONTEX'.
  - 'ENUMLOGFONTEX' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or
  defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.   String get elfStyle
  => addressOf
  ^^^^^^^^^
- /D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:1126:27:
  Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class
  'ENUMLOGFONTEX'.
  - 'ENUMLOGFONTEX' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or
  defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.   String get elfScript
  => addressOf
  ^^^^^^^^^
- /D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2688:7:
  Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class
  'OSVERSIONINFO'.
  - 'OSVERSIONINFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or
  defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  addressOf.cast().elementAt(20).cast().unpackString(128);
  ^^^^^^^^^
- /D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2699:11:
  Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class
  'OSVERSIONINFO'.
  - 'OSVERSIONINFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or
  defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  ..addressOf.cast().elementAt(20).value = 0;
  ^^^^^^^^^
- /D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2744:24:
  Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class
  'BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO'.
  - 'BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or
  defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.   String get szName =>
  addressOf
  ^^^^^^^^^
- /D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2837:7:
  Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class
  'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO'.
  - 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or
  defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  addressOf.cast().elementAt(BTH_MAX_PIN_SIZE).value;
  ^^^^^^^^^
- /D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2840:5:
  Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class
  'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO'.
  - 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or
  defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  addressOf.cast().elementAt(BTH_MAX_PIN_SIZE).value =
  ^^^^^^^^^
- /D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2845:28:
  Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class
  'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO'.
  - 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or
  defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  String.fromCharCodes(addressOf.cast().asTypedList(pinLength));
  ^^^^^^^^^
- /D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2853:7:
  Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class
  'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO'.
  - 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or
  defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  addressOf.cast().elementAt(idx).value = pinData[idx];
  ^^^^^^^^^
- /D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/com/combase.dart:38:31:
  Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
  - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or
  defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.   final iid =
  GUID.allocate().addressOf;
  ^^^^^^^^^
- /D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/com/combase.dart:56:33:
  Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
  - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or
  defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.   final clsid =
  GUID.allocate().addressOf;
  ^^^^^^^^^
- /D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/winrt/winrt_helpers.dart:86:40:
  Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
  - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or
  defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.   final riidCalendar =
  GUID.allocate().addressOf;
  ^^^^^^^^^
- /D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IDesktopWallpaper.dart:197:38:
  Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class
  'COMObject'.
  - 'COMObject' is from 'package:win32/src/com/combase.dart' ('/D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/com/combase.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or
  defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  final ptr = COMObject.allocate().addressOf;
  ^^^^^^^^^
- /D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IDesktopWallpaper.dart:200:49:
  Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
  - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or
  defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  GUID.fromString(CLSID_DesktopWallpaper).addressOf,
  ^^^^^^^^^
- /D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IDesktopWallpaper.dart:203:48:
  Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
  - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or
  defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  GUID.fromString(IID_IDesktopWallpaper).addressOf,
  ^^^^^^^^^
- /D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IFileOpenDialog.dart:58:38:
  Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for  the class
  'COMObject'.
  - 'COMObject' is from 'package:win32/src/com/combase.dart' ('/D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/com/combase.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or
  defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  final ptr = COMObject.allocate().addressOf;
  ^^^^^^^^^
- /D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IFileOpenDialog.dart:61:47:
  Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for  the class 'GUID'.
  - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or
  defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  GUID.fromString(CLSID_FileOpenDialog).addressOf,
  ^^^^^^^^^
- /D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IFileOpenDialog.dart:64:46:
  Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for  the class 'GUID'.
  - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or
  defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  GUID.fromString(IID_IFileOpenDialog).addressOf,
  ^^^^^^^^^
- /D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IFileSaveDialog.dart:99:38:
  Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for  the class
  'COMObject'.
  - 'COMObject' is from 'package:win32/src/com/combase.dart' ('/D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/com/combase.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or
  defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  final ptr = COMObject.allocate().addressOf;
  ^^^^^^^^^
- /D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IFileSaveDialog.dart:102:47:
  Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
  - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or
  defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  GUID.fromString(CLSID_FileSaveDialog).addressOf,
  ^^^^^^^^^
- /D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IFileSaveDialog.dart:105:46:
  Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
  - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or
  defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  GUID.fromString(IID_IFileSaveDialog).addressOf,
  ^^^^^^^^^
- /D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IKnownFolderManager.dart:164:38: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class
  'COMObject'.
  - 'COMObject' is from 'package:win32/src/com/combase.dart' ('/D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/com/combase.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or
  defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  final ptr = COMObject.allocate().addressOf;
  ^^^^^^^^^
- /D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IKnownFolderManager.dart:167:51: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
  - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or
  defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  GUID.fromString(CLSID_KnownFolderManager).addressOf,
  ^^^^^^^^^
- /D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IKnownFolderManager.dart:170:50: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
  - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or
  defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  GUID.fromString(IID_IKnownFolderManager).addressOf,
  ^^^^^^^^^
- /D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/INetworkListManager.dart:128:38: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class
  'COMObject'.
  - 'COMObject' is from 'package:win32/src/com/combase.dart' ('/D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/com/combase.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or
  defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  final ptr = COMObject.allocate().addressOf;
  ^^^^^^^^^
- /D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/INetworkListManager.dart:131:51: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
  - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or
  defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  GUID.fromString(CLSID_NetworkListManager).addressOf,
  ^^^^^^^^^
- /D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/INetworkListManager.dart:134:50: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
  - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or
  defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  GUID.fromString(IID_INetworkListManager).addressOf,
  ^^^^^^^^^
- /D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IWbemLocator.dart:82:38:
  Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class
  'COMObject'.
  - 'COMObject' is from 'package:win32/src/com/combase.dart' ('/D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/com/combase.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or
  defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  final ptr = COMObject.allocate().addressOf;
  ^^^^^^^^^
- /D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IWbemLocator.dart:84:68:
  Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
  - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or
  defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  final hr = CoCreateInstance(GUID.fromString(CLSID_WbemLocator).addressOf,
  ^^^^^^^^^
- /D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IWbemLocator.dart:85:64:
  Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
  - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or
  defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  nullptr, CLSCTX_ALL, GUID.fromString(IID_IWbemLocator).addressOf, ptr);
  ^^^^^^^^^
- /D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/utf8.dart:63:33:
  Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'Utf8'.
  - 'Utf8' is from 'package:ffi/src/utf8.dart' ('/D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/utf8.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or
  defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.   String toString() =>
  fromUtf8(addressOf);
  ^^^^^^^^^
- /D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:1111:7:
  Error: Struct 'ENUMLOGFONTEX' is empty. Empty structs are undefined
  behavior. class ENUMLOGFONTEX extends Struct {
  ^
- /D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2835:7:
  Error: Struct 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO' is empty. Empty structs are
  undefined behavior. class BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO extends Struct {
  ^
- /D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2960:7:
  Error: Struct 'EXCEPINFO' is empty. Empty structs are undefined
  behavior. class EXCEPINFO extends Struct {}
  ^
- /D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2966:7:
  Error: Struct 'PROPERTYKEY' is empty. Empty structs are undefined
  behavior. class PROPERTYKEY extends Struct {}
  ^
- /D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2973:7:
  Error: Struct 'PROPVARIANT' is empty. Empty structs are undefined
  behavior. class PROPVARIANT extends Struct {}
  ^
- /D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2978:7:
  Error: Struct 'SAFEARRAY' is empty. Empty structs are undefined
  behavior. class SAFEARRAY extends Struct {}
  ^
- /D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2985:7:
  Error: Struct 'CLSID' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
  class CLSID extends Struct {}
  ^
- /D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2992:7:
  Error: Struct 'STATSTG' is empty. Empty structs are undefined
  behavior. class STATSTG extends Struct {}
  ^
- /D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2999:7:
  Error: Struct 'NLM_SIMULATED_PROFILE_INFO' is empty. Empty structs
  are undefined behavior. class NLM_SIMULATED_PROFILE_INFO extends
  Struct {}
  ^
- /D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/utf8.dart:23:7:
  Error: Struct 'Utf8' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
  class Utf8 extends Struct {
  ^
- /D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/utf16.dart:16:7:
  Error: Struct 'Utf16' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
  class Utf16 extends Struct {
  ^
- /D:/app/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/allocation.dart:47:33:
  Error: Expected type 'T' to be a valid and instantiated subtype of
  'NativeType'.   final int totalSize = count * sizeOf();
  ^
- FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

  - Where:
    -Script 'D:\app\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1035
  - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

  > Process 'command 'D:\app\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

- Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

  - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
- BUILD FAILED in 17s
- Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
- Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        18.1s
- Exception:  Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

———————————————————————————————————————————————————————

And here is the flutter doctor -v log:

- [√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version
  10.0.18363.1440], locale zh-CN)

  • Flutter version 2.2.3 at D:\app\flutter

  • Framework revision f4abaa0735 (4 weeks ago), 2021-07-01 12:46:11 -0700

  • Engine revision 241c87ad80

  • Dart version 2.13.4

  • Pub download mirror https://pub.flutter-io.cn

  • Flutter download mirror https://storage.flutter-io.cn

  [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
  version 30.0.3)

   • Android SDK at C:\Users\HBin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

   • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3

   • Java binary at: D:\app\Android Studio\jre\bin\java

  • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174)

   • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web

  • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio

  • Android Studio at D:\app\Android Studio

  • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter

 • Dart plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart

 • android-studio-dir = D:\app\Android Studio

 • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174)

[√] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2020.3)

 • IntelliJ at D:\app\IntelliJ IDEA\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3

• Flutter plugin version 53.1.5

• Dart plugin version 203.8173

[√] Connected device (3 available)

 • MI 9 (mobile) • 127.0.0.1:62001 • android-x86    • Android 7.1.2 (API 25)

 • Chrome (web)  • chrome          • web-javascript • Google Chrome 91.0.4472.164

 • Edge (web)    • edge            • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 91.0.864.54

• No issues found!

here is the pubspec.yaml

name: bdmap_loc_flutter_plugin_demo

description: bdmap location flutter plugin demo

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.

# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43

# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.

# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter

# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.

# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.

# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning

# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.

# Read more about iOS versioning at

# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:

  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:

  flutter:

    sdk: flutter

  flutter_bmflocation: ^1.0.3

# The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.

  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

  flutter_bmfutils: ^1.0.2

  flutter_bmfmap:  ^1.0.2

  flutter_screenutil: ^3.2.0

  gzx_dropdown_menu: ^2.1.0

  flutter_picker: ^1.1.5

  http: ^0.12.2

  toast: ^0.1.5

  shared_preferences: ^0.5.12+4

  pull_to_refresh: ^1.6.3

  flutter_swiper: ^1.1.6

  smooth_star_rating: 1.1.1

  dotted_border: ^1.0.7

  image_picker: ^0.6.7+17

  image_crop: ^0.3.4

  web_socket_channel: ^1.1.0

  event_bus: ^1.1.1

  url_launcher: ^5.7.10

  permission_handler: ^5.0.1+1

dev_dependencies:

  flutter_test:

    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the

# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

# The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is

  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in

  # the material Icons class.
uses-material-design: true

...

Comment: add your pubspec.yaml  chanes are they were using an old flutter version.